# Python TypeError

Tags: python, types

So I have the code:

```
intex = input("Enter in a letter of text\n")
if intex == 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r':
    counter += intex
    print(counter)
```

By the way, all the letters are defined, I just didn't think it was neccessary to put them in,(a = 1, b= 2, etc.) but whenever I run the code, it gives me the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`

I know what this error means, that i cant add a letter to a number, but is there a way to do this without the error? i tried float(), but that gave me another error! please help!

Comment: `intex == 'a' or 'b' or 'c'` What do you think this does?  Can you explain this code snippet?  It's unlike any Python I've ever seen.

Comment: `counter += input('Enter in a letter of text\n') in 'abcdefghijklmnopqr'`

Comment: What is `counter` counting?  How will you use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `or` operator does not work the way you think.  The expression `a or b` returns `a` if it has a trucy [truth value](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), and to `b` otherwise.  You probably mean

```
if intex in "abcdefghijklmnopqr":
    ...
```

To translate the letter into an integer such that `a` maps to `1` etc, you can use [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord):

```
counter += ord(intex) - ord("a") + 1
```

Comment: gives me this error TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found

Comment: @SolomonWise: I added further information -- the answer originally only consisted of the first part or `or`.

Comment: @SolomonWise: Did you actually *try* the code?  Did you follow the link to the documentation of `ord()`?

Answer (score 4):

```
if intex == 'a' or 'b' or 'c'
```

should instead be `intex == 'a' or intex == 'b' ...`

An easier way to do this would be to use the `in` operator.
I can only assume that you want something like this to store the values somewhere.

```
my_list = []
if ord(intex) >= ord("a") and ord(intex) <=ord("r"):
     my_list.append(ord(intex))
```

Could you specify what the code should do? It looks rather strange.

Comment: this gives me error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Comment: sorry, dunno what I was thinking. what are you trying to do? your code does not make much sense. why are you adding the string to a counter?

Comment: i am converting letters to numbers

Comment: The new version will error out if the user enters a string consisting of more than one character.  I thought about all this before I wrote my answer -- this is why I did *not* use comparison operators, but `in`.

Comment: ok, sorry, the whole post has been a mess from the start. should not try to post on SO when i'm tired, made so many mistakes during so many edits. +1 to you.

Comment: @UkuLoskit: I've done much worse than this in some posts when I was tired. :)